# Excel formula to return value of cell in column A based off the relative cell value in column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a spreadsheet that has order number's in column A and the associated dates in column B. I can seem to get a correctly functioning formula that will find the earliest date in column B and return the associated order number from column A.

I've tried using INDEX and VLOOKUP formulas and managed to get it to return a date using `=MIN(IF(B$1:B$99,A$1:A$99,""))` but when reversed it only returns the lowest order number.

`=MIN(IF(B$1:B$99,A$1:A$99,""))`Returns lowest date or lowest order number.

I need the order number associated with the earliest date

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(MIN(B1:B10),B1:B10,0))
```

Used sample range for orders `A1:A10` and dates `B1:B10`. Just change accordingly.

Comment: It's returning #N/A using the above formula

Comment: @ZCastel Try fixing ranges with `$`

Comment: It isn't, it's a lookup formula.